# Q: Import Uikit in yii\bootstrap\NavBar

Tags: css, yii2, uikit, navbar

I use Yii2 framework and I'm writing a navbar in layout/main.php. I have to use Uikit so I imported css and js files in my project, now the problem is that yii\bootstrap\NavBar seems not to be customizable and doesn't support uikit classes. Is there a way to use uk classes and span tag with yii navbar?

I have this HTML code:

```
<nav class="uk-navbar-container" uk-navbar>
<div class="uk-navbar-left">
    <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
        <li class="uk-active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Parent</a>
            <div class="uk-navbar-dropdown">
                <ul class="uk-nav uk-navbar-dropdown-nav">
                    <li class="uk-active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item
                    <span class="uk-icon uk-margin-small-right" uk-icon="icon: star"></span>
                    </a></li>
                    <li class="uk-nav-header">Header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li class="uk-nav-divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="uk-navbar-right">
    <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Parent</a>
            <div class="uk-navbar-dropdown">
                <ul class="uk-nav uk-navbar-dropdown-nav">
                    <li class="uk-active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li class="uk-nav-header">Header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li class="uk-nav-divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and this is the implementation with yii2 component:

```
NavBar::begin([
'brandLabel' => Html::img('/img/my_image.png'),
'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
'options' => [
    'class' => 'uk-navbar navbar-fixed-top uk-align-center',
    'style' => 'background-color: orange; color: black ; height: 100px; 
    margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0',
    ]
 ]);
$menuItems = [
['label' => 'Home', 'url' => Yii::$app->homeUrl],
['label' => 'Item', 'url' => ['/item']],
['label' => 'Item', 'url' => ['/item']],
['label' => 'Item', 'url' => ['/item']],
['label' => 'Item', 'url' => ['/item']],
echo Nav::widget([
'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right uk-link-reset',
              'style' => 'color: white'
             ],
'items' => $menuItems,
]);
NavBar::end();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include html options inside each individual item

```
$menuItems = [
    ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => Yii::$app->homeUrl],
    [
        'label'   => 'Item <span class="uk-icon uk-margin-small-right" uk-icon="icon: star"></span>',
        'encode'  => false,
        'url'     => ['/item'],
        'options' => ['class' => 'uk-active'],
    ],
    ['label' => 'Item', 'url' => ['/item']],
    ['label' => 'Item', 'url' => ['/item']],
    ['label' => 'Item', 'url' => ['/item']]
];
```

More details from the item [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/doc/api/2.1/yii-bootstrap-nav#$items-detail):

> - **label**: string, required, the nav item label.
> - **url**: optional, the item's URL. Defaults to "#".
> - **visible**: boolean, optional, whether this menu item is visible. Defaults to true.
> - **linkOptions**: array, optional, the HTML attributes of the item's link.
> - **options**: array, optional, the HTML attributes of the item container (LI).
> - **active**: boolean, optional, whether the item should be on active state or not.
> - **dropDownOptions**: array, optional, the HTML options that will passed to the `yii\bootstrap\Dropdown` widget.
> - **items**: array|string, optional, the configuration array for creating a `yii\bootstrap\Dropdown` widget, or a string representing the dropdown menu. Note that Bootstrap does not support sub-dropdown menus.
> - **encode**: boolean, optional, whether the label will be HTML-encoded. If set, supersedes the $encodeLabels option for only this item.

Comment: Thank you, just one doubt: in this way will the code be responsive?

Comment: that depends on the css theme you apply. the point here is to have the `Nav` object render its elements exactly the way you need it

Comment: It worked but watching from mobile the navbar fades away, can you please help me to show a sidebar with navbar items displayed as list?